# Is it possible to partition data based on column which may contain empty value sometimes? how to handle it?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v.
I need to join two datasets ds1 and ds2 (new-column) based on some field.
val resultDs = ds1.join(ds2,  , "inner");

resultDs now contain "new-column" but for the records which not met   does not have this "new-column". Hence for those records I need to set this  "new-column"  null/empty.

But as per my business requirement I need to parition the resultDs on "new-column".
so how generally these kind of scenarios are handled ? pleas advice.

Comment: You can use a left join instead of inner, that will keep all rows from `df1` and automatically put a null in the columns with no matching row in `df2`. See here for different join types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark As for how to handle the partitioning in this case, is there any default value? If not, what to do would depend on the actual business requirement.

Comment: Using left join the new column will have nulls automatically. Since you want to partition on the column, you could replace the nulls with a default value (or impute the values with forward-fill, etc) or you could keep them as null. Both should be ok.

Comment: Forward fill would be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621319/spark-scala-forward-fill-with-last-observation , an alternative would to be to replace with mean values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057563/replace-missing-values-with-mean-spark-dataframe To get rows that differ between two dataframes you can use `except`/`subtract` or leftanti join: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270373/how-to-implement-except-in-apache-spark-based-on-subset-of-columns/49270468#49270468 (when done on a subset of the columns).